# How to find out what all standalone packages are installed?

Tags: linux, rpm

I am trying to find the version of tomcat which was installed from a tar file not through **yum**, So how do we find out that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With java installed, go into the `tomcat/bin` directory and run this command:

```
./version.sh
```

The output will be in this format:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.33
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.33
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.33/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.33/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.33/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
Server version: Apache Tomcat/9.0.33
Server built:   Mar 11 2020 09:31:38 UTC
Server number:  9.0.33.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     4.18.0-147.5.1.el8_1.x86_64
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    11.0.6+10-LTS
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

Comment: How do we check at first place that tomcat is installed in the Linux machine, then only I can do what you have mentioned.

Comment: @DharmenderLodhi Use `locate` or `find`.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot!